# Reformatting date & time does not change after using VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, date, formatting

I am trying to take a file with the date being mm/dd/yyyy and reformat it to yyyy-mm-dd and output that new format to a new sheet, but even after running my VBS macro it does not change although the birthDate is correct. I have seen that there is issues with Excel overwritting your format to US regardless. Is there any way around this? Thanks!

```
birthDate = Trim(CStr(Sheet1.Cells(currRawRow, "F")))
    checkInput = InStr(1, birthDate, "/")

If (checkInput > 0) Then
birthYear = Year(birthDate)
birthMonth = Month(birthDate)
birthDay = Day(birthDate)

birthMonth = Format(CStr(birthMonth), "00")
birthDay = Format(CStr(birthDay), "00")
birthYear = Format(CStr(birthYear), "0000")

birthDate = (birthYear & "-" & birthMonth & "-" & birthDay)
```

Comment: Just use the Format function. E.g. my_string = Format(birthDate,"yyyy-mm-dd")

Comment: This indeed formats it, but when outputing the formatted date to a cell in a new sheet, it doesnt keep the formatting.

Comment: Then set the format of the cell to the appropriate date format.

Comment: Yes but this would require anyone who opens the file to do this no? And if it is looping through cells long of info and then outputting to alot of cells how would this be done?

Comment: After you paste your data to the worksheet `Sheet1.Range("A1:Z1000").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"` or whatever you need.

Comment: Could you please provide some examples of date in  column F? If the initial format is mm/dd/yyyy why you check for "/"?

Answer (score 0):

Any number recognised as a date by Excel will display in the short date format of the control panel regional settings ->Date & Time for whomever opened the file.

To override this, either:
1) set the format explicitly as part of you loop as Daimian suggests or;
2) force the format to string, by preceding the date by a single quote.

e.g in your last line of code change:

birthDate = (birthYear & "-" & birthMonth & "-" & birthDay)

to

birthDate = "'" & (birthYear & "-" & birthMonth & "-" & birthDay)